# Inserting space, padding between images with CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am trying to add some images into a space which will comprise two rows of 3 images each, so 6 in total.

I have created a fiddle with the code in here http://jsfiddle.net/swAXU/2/

The images show how I would want them, however I want to add padding, or space in between each image to space them out?

Can anyone tell me how this can be done as changing the margin and padding attributes make no difference?

Comment: Did you try reloading the page to clear the stylesheet cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you wanna get really fancy...

http://jsfiddle.net/swAXU/11/

Comment: Must be something additional in my code causing conflicts, if i change my css to your fancy stuff, it makes no difference

Comment: Or, as an alternative, reference them directly by giving each image an ID.

Answer (score 1):

Adding margins does work: http://jsfiddle.net/swAXU/9/

Your CSS selectors were off. I just changed

```
.slidedeck dd.slide_3 img
```

to

```
.slidedeck dd img
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were just accessing them wrong via css.

This works...

```
.slidedeck img {margin:20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{margin:10px;}
```

?

That works... http://jsfiddle.net/Ep6rb/

Comment: hhhmm, must be something additional in my code then causing an issue.  No matter what I change, it doesn't affect the spacing on my images at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<dd>` element has no class.

Change your selector to `.slidedeck dd img`.

Comment: I have tried that. Even with all the suggestions on here, my images never change